# HTML Drop Down List with Timer

Tags: javascript, html, select, counter, stopwatch

I have a question regarding the implementation of a Stopwatch written with Javascript in the select field for my homepage:

```
<select name="dropdown">
<option value="Project 1" selected>Project 1</option>
<option value="Project 2" selected>Project 2</option>
<option value="Project 3" selected>Project 3</option>
<option value="Project 4" selected>Project 4</option>
</select>
```

Everytime I choose Project 1, I want to start the stopwatch in the option field near its name "Project 1" . It has to look like this:

Project 1 time (the time has to be implemented in the option field)

I want the first click to start the stopwatch and the second click on the option field to stop the stop watch.

Here is the Javascript code for the stopwatch:

```
Stopwatch = function(listener, resolution) {
    this.startTime = 0;
    this.stopTime = 0;
    this.totalElapsed = 0; // * elapsed number of ms in total
    this.started = false;
    this.listener = (listener != undefined ? listener : null); // * function to receive onTick events
    this.tickResolution = (resolution != undefined ? resolution : 500); // * how long between each tick in milliseconds
    this.tickInterval = null;

    // * pretty static vars
    this.onehour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
    this.onemin  = 1000 * 60;
    this.onesec  = 1000;
}
Stopwatch.prototype.start = function() {
    var delegate = function(that, method) { return function() { return method.call(that) } };
    if(!this.started) {
        this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
        this.stopTime = 0;
        this.started = true;
        this.tickInterval = setInterval(delegate(this, this.onTick), this.tickResolution);
    }
}
Stopwatch.prototype.stop = function() {
    if(this.started) {
        this.stopTime = new Date().getTime();
        this.started = false;
        var elapsed = this.stopTime - this.startTime;
        this.totalElapsed += elapsed;
        if(this.tickInterval != null)
            clearInterval(this.tickInterval);
    }
    return this.getElapsed();
}
Stopwatch.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.totalElapsed = 0;
    // * if watch is running, reset it to current time
    this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
    this.stopTime = this.startTime;
}
Stopwatch.prototype.restart = function() {
    this.stop();
    this.reset();
    this.start();
}
Stopwatch.prototype.getElapsed = function() {
    // * if watch is stopped, use that date, else use now
    var elapsed = 0;
    if(this.started)
        elapsed = new Date().getTime() - this.startTime;
    elapsed += this.totalElapsed;

    var hours = parseInt(elapsed / this.onehour);
    elapsed %= this.onehour;
    var mins = parseInt(elapsed / this.onemin);
    elapsed %= this.onemin;
    var secs = parseInt(elapsed / this.onesec);
    var ms = elapsed % this.onesec;

    return {
        hours: hours,
        minutes: mins,
        seconds: secs,
        milliseconds: ms
    };
}
Stopwatch.prototype.setElapsed = function(hours, mins, secs) {
    this.reset();
    this.totalElapsed = 0;
    this.totalElapsed += hours * this.onehour;
    this.totalElapsed += mins  * this.onemin;
    this.totalElapsed += secs  * this.onesec;
    this.totalElapsed = Math.max(this.totalElapsed, 0); // * No negative numbers
}
Stopwatch.prototype.toString = function() {
    var zpad = function(no, digits) {
        no = no.toString();
        while(no.length < digits)
            no = '0' + no;
        return no;
    }
    var e = this.getElapsed();
    return zpad(e.hours,2) + ":" + zpad(e.minutes,2) + ":" + zpad(e.seconds,2);
}
Stopwatch.prototype.setListener = function(listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
// * triggered every <resolution> ms
Stopwatch.prototype.onTick = function() {
    if(this.listener != null) {
        this.listener(this);
    }
}
```

Please forgive my ignorance. I'm a beginner in this field and I am trying to understand how to implement and how to use this code.